.NET Core Visual Studio Kestrel F5 Debugging - Shell Window - PS1 Profile
Starting a Visual Studio Debugger on a Kestrel Project starts a Command Window with standard out content.
I happen to have a complex profile.ps1 that setups many custom functions and aliases.  I do not that to run for this F5 Command Window.
Is there a way to suppress the Powershell Profile when starting the Visual Studio Debugger with a .NET Core Project such that the any shell startup logic, such as setting up PS1 custom aliases, does not run?

Important:

This answer - due to a misreading of the question - offers a solution for Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio.


From the Terminal Profiles documentation topic, section Configuring the task/debug profile:

By default, the task/debug features will use the default profile. This may not be ideal if your default has a heavy PowerShell startup script or a non-POSIX compliant shell for example. To configure a profile to be used only in the debug/tasks features, use the terminal.integrated.automationProfile.<platform> setting

E.g., on Windows, add the following to your settings.json file (using the Settings dialog (Ctrl+, you can search for automation, which will take you to the Terminal › Integrated › Automation Profile: entries, which provides platform-specific links for directly editing settings.json):
// An entry in the user's settings.json

  "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows": {
    "path": "powershell.exe",
    "args": [ "-noprofile" ]
  }

Note:

The above assumes Windows PowerShell; if you'd rather use PowerShell (Core) 7, replace powershell.exe with pwsh.exe (with the latter being assumed to be discoverable via $env:PATH; if not, specify a full path, using either / or \\ as the path (directory) separator).

Caveat:

Visual Studio Code implicitly passes the "command" string associated with the task being invoked via the -Command parameter of the PowerShell CLI; for cmd.exe, it uses /d /c, and on Unix-like platforms it uses -c.

As such, that command string must be PowerShell-compatible; notably, any references to environment variables must use $env:<variable-name> syntax.

If that cannot be ensured, consider using the platform-native (legacy) shell instead, which on Windows means cmd.exe, and on Unix-like platforms /bin/sh; e.g., on Windows:
"terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows": {
  "path": "cmd.exe"
}






My question is about the launchsettings.json file of Visual Studio not VS Code.
Anyone know the equivalent launchsettings.json commands / object for the VS Code terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows ?

@HowardHoffman: Oops! Sorry, totally misread your question. I'm not familiar with Visual Studio, but based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/project-settings-for-csharp-debug-configurations-dotnetcore?view=vs-2022#launch-profile-net-core-net-5 you may have to specify -NoProfile under the "Command-line arguments" settings in the Open debug launch profiles UI.
